# Multiple filters on a collection with angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm following the [Meteor To-Do App tutorial with Angular integration](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/filtering-collections) and am learning about filtering collections. I've been able to implement a simple filter on a collection for the app I'm working on by following the principles in the tutorial, but now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to add multiple queries to the filter.

In the example, you can view incomplete tasks by toggling a checkbox. This is implemented in the controller by watching `$scope.hideCompleted` for changes and passing it as a Mongo query to filter the Meteor collection.

**Watcher**

```
$scope.$watch('hideCompleted', function() {
  if ($scope.hideCompleted)
    $scope.query = {checked: {$ne: true}};
  else
    $scope.query = {};
});
```

**Collection filter**

```
$scope.tasks = $meteor.collection(function() {
  return Tasks.find($scope.getReactively('query'), {sort: {createdAt: -1}})
});
```

*How do I make the query support multiple filters?* For example, say I've chosen to extend the example and have ranked each to-do item by priority. I then would have an an input field for the user to filter the collection by priority, whose value is bound to `$scope.priority`. Now, if I wanted to filter the to-do list by incomplete and priority=$scope.priority tasks, I understand the Mongo query would need to be something along the lines of `Tasks.find({ $and: [{ checked: {$ne: true} },{ priority: $scope.priority }]},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 } })`.

In my app, I've been able to make two watchers properly track changes to two scope variables, analogous to my example with `$scope.hideCompleted` and `$scope.priority`, but I don't know how to take the next step to merge the queries when filtering the collection. I've also tinkered around a little with [this package](https://github.com/julianmontagna/filter-collections), since I'll eventually hope to be able to filter and sort by many criteria, but I didn't get too far with it before switching to the concepts I've described here.

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
    // uncomment subscribe after you've got to that point
    // $scope.$meteorSubscribe('yourSubscription').then(function() {
        $scope.tasks = $scope.$meteorCollection(function() {
            return Tasks.find({ 
                checked: $scope.getReactively('model.hideCompleted'),
                priority: $scope.getReactively('model.priority')
            }, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
        });
    // });
});
```

A couple of things here:

1. Once you have removed `autopublish` you can uncomment the `$scope.$meteorSubscribe` method and replace `"yourSubscription"` with the name of your actual subscription.
2. `$meteor.autorun` will fire every time any `getReactively` variable changes.
3. `$scope.$meteorSubscribe` and `$scope.$meteorCollection` are favored as they will remove the subscriptions and object/collection when the scope is destroyed.

If you have any issues then perhaps I can setup a demo for you to look at.

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward and accomplishes the same thing in fewer lines. I handle the subscription elsewhere in the controller, so I might need to do some adjustments, but I think I'll prefer this approach as it accomplishes the same thing in fewer lines. I also need to read up on $meteorSubscribe and $meteorCollection.

Comment: Awesome, don't hesitate to start a new question if you get stuck with your adjustments. Also, if you don't mind, mark the correct answers so they're easier for others to find ;)

Comment: Yeah, I planned to mark it once I'd tested it out. :) I'm trying it out this morning, at it seems to work pretty well, and it wasn't too bad to adjust my existing code. However, I noticed this will apply the filters before any the model is changed at all (i.e., returns no to-do tasks at the start since all of the tasks have a priority assigned, and it works once the client sets the priority in the input form).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I was a lot closer than I had expected, so I'll answer my question and share what I did to implement multiple filters with regards to the hypothetical extension of the to-do app.

I made `hideCompleted` and `priority` scope variables into properties of a scope object `model`, and used a single watcher with the argument `true` at the end to check for object equality (for *any* changes to `model` or its properties). I then generated `$scope.query` by stitching together "sub-queries." I've added the code below.

This seems to be working fine for now, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution, so I will continue experimenting, and I will update my answer if I find anything better. I'd be interested in any other approaches, though!

**Watcher**

```
var initQuery=true;    
var subQueries=[];
$scope.$watch('model', function() {
  if (!initQuery){
    subQueries=[];
    if ($scope.model.hideCompleted)
      subQueries.push({checked: {$ne: true}});
    if ($scope.model.priority)
      subQueries.push({priority: $scope.model.priority});
    $scope.query = { $and: subQueries};
  } else {
    initQuery = false;
    $scope.query = {};
  }
}, true);
```

**Filter Collections** (unchanged)

```
$scope.tasks = $meteor.collection(function() {
  return Tasks.find($scope.getReactively('query'), {sort: {createdAt: -1}})
});
```

Comment: Are you building all your queries client side? What would happen if I edited your Tasks.find call? Make sure you are handling the rules serverside

Comment: @Neil Would you expand on what you mean by editing my Tasks.find call and handling the rules serverside? I'm now using a variation of both of the answers here, but in any case, in the publish function server side, I have rules for the queries, sorting, etc.

Comment: I was just pointing out that you need to make sure you handle the rules in serverside so that if i maliciously edit your client side Task.find, I cannot mess with your db. Most people use allow / deny rules, but I find this lib to be really useful - https://github.com/ongoworks/meteor-security

Comment: @Neil Good point. I've noticed the tutorials I've followed generally assume that the users won't try to mess with the db, which is a little disappointing. Do you have any resources you could point me to so I can learn to better secure the app this way?